# how to avoid a type error when finding the median of a list

Tags: python

I am working on a project to get the mean, median and mode of a list. I have it almost all down but the median function is giving me the following error:

> return (list[midIndex]+list[midIndex-1])/2.0
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float

```
def median(list):
   if len(list) == 0:
       return 0
   list.sort()
   midIndex = len(list)/2
   if len(list)%2 == 0:
       return (list[midIndex]+list[midIndex-1])/2
   else:
       return list[midIndex]

def mean(list):
   if len(list) == 0:
       return 0
   list.sort()
   total = 0
   for number in list:
       total += number
   return total / len(list)

def mode(list):
   numberDictionary = {}
   for digit in list:
       number = numberDictionary.get(digit, None)
       if number == None:
           numberDictionary[digit] = 1
       else:
           numberDictionary[digit] = number+1
   maxValue = max(numberDictionary.values())
   modeList = []
   for key in numberDictionary:
       if numberDictionary[key] == maxValue:
           modeList.append(key)
   return modeList

def main():
   lyst = [3, 1, 7, 1, 4, 10]
   print("List:", lyst)
   print("Mode", mode(lyst))
   print("Median:", median(lyst))
   print("Mean:", mean(lyst))
main()
```

The answer should be 3.5.

Comment: `len(lst) / 2` returns `float`, you can't use it as an index. Try floor division instead `len(lst) // 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see that len division by two will result in a float type and can't be used as an index (python error message is clear).

```
list = {1,2,3,4}
midIndex = len(list)/2
print(f"midIndex = {midIndex}")
print(type(midIndex))

Output:
midIndex = 2.0
<class 'float'>
```